# How to use one HAProxy server for multiple domain

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have the below-mentioned scenario:

I have two domains let's say domain **D1** & domain **D2**

Machines I have :

Machine **M1LB** that is for Load Balancer (HA Proxy)

Machine **D1M1** & **D1M2**, that is for Application 1

Machine **D2M1** & **D2M2**, that is for Application 2

Traffic of domain D1 should go on **D1M1** & **D1M2** machines with Load Balancer **M1LB**, Similarly for domain D2 should go on **D2M1** & **D2M2** machines.

Now, what is the best way to configure Load balancer with the help of only 1 machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define two backends, and route by domain in frontend like this:

```
frontend http-in
        bind *:80

        acl host_d1 hdr(host) -i d1.com
        acl host_d2 hdr(host) -i d2.com

        use_backend be_d1 if host_d1
        use_backend be_d2 if host_d2

backend be_d1
        server D1M1 10.0.0.1:8080 
        server D1M2 10.0.0.2:8080 

backend be_d2
        server D2M1 10.0.0.1:8080 
        server D2M2 10.0.0.2:8080
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, If I need to use https, How to define ssl keys for each domain name?